# Enable / Disable button (Bootstrap 3) using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button that is styled with Bootstrap3, not sure if that really matters or not....

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" disabled="disabled" id="transmitDirectMail">Send</button>
```

And I have an jquery ajax that validates an input and enables/disables the button if the value is a valid Direct Mail.

```
$("#directMailAddress")
    .keyup(function () {
        transmitToDirectEmail = this.value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./phiMail/ValidateDirectMail.php",
            cache: false,
            data: { dMail: transmitToDirectEmail }
        })
            .done(function( msg ) {
                if (msg = "0")
                    $("#transmitDirectMail").prop('disabled', true);;
                if (msg = "1")
                    $("#transmitDirectMail").prop('disabled', false);
            });
    });
```

The problem is that setting the prop enables the button. The ('disabled', true) does not disable the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you are using `=` (*assignment operator*) instead of `==` or `===` for comparison.

```
.done(function( msg ) {
    $("#transmitDirectMail").prop('disabled', msg == "0");
});
```

Comment: Sometimes it's the simple things. Just a typo in my code. Thank you.